# How to deal with abbreviations at the end of a question?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, abbreviations

In a sentence like

> Should we host them on imgur et cetera?

where I want to abbreviate the "et cetera", what is the correct punctuation? Using a period after the "etc." like mid sentence usages seems wrong as it looks like a full stop when I read it.

> Should we host them on imgur etc.?

Or is this the correct usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When "etc." is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable to use a question mark immediately after an abbreviation ending in a period.

> In the case of an interrogative or exclamatory sentence ending with an abbreviation, a question or exclamation mark can still be added (e.g., Are you Gabriel Gama, Jr.?).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop).

Comment: Am I the only person who got to the end of this quote and started considering how many times I could nest examples to get lots of punctuation validly adjacent at the end of a sentence?  This could be a fun contest!  ^_^

Comment: Let's see it, then.

Comment: @Scivitri You mean validly adjacent punctuation like in Hal's quote above stating "In the case of an interrogative of exclamatory sentence ending with an abbreviation, a question or exclamation mark can still be added (e.g., Are you Gabriel Gama, Jr.?)."? :-D (I can't comment yet...)