# punctuation when abbreviation at the end

Tags: punctuation

It's about using the right punctuation when abbreviation is used at the end of sentence. It has been asked here when the sentence is a question: [How to deal with abbreviations at the end of a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19434/how-to-deal-with-abbreviations-at-the-end-of-a-question).

What about sentences like the following:

```
The opinions of this articles are those of the author(s),
and do not necessarily reflect the views of Google Inc..
```

Two dots or one dot?

Answer (score 3):

Common practice is to use only one period at the end of a sentence when an abbreviation would use a period.  For other punctuation, such as a comma or semicolon, both the abbreviation's period and the other punctuation mark would typically be used.  The issue might often be avoided by expanding the abbreviation.