# How should the end of a question be punctuated if the last word is an abbr.?

Tags: punctuation

The question itself is an example, but it isn't the best example

```
Have you ever visited D.C.?
```

or

```
Have you ever visited D.C?
```

Both look wrong to me. The former has double punctuation, which is against the rules, at least most of the time. The latter doesn't have a period indicating that the C is an abbreviation.

Comment: I think this is General Reference/common knowledge. Obviously, many results returned by searching Google Books for [Do you live in L.A.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22do+you+live+in+L.A.%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) sidestep the issue by not bothering with *either* period. But I don't think there would be a single (valid) instance where only the second period was discarded (supposedly, "replaced" by the question mark).

Comment: This is a repeat of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19434/63159