# Ending sentences with "etc"

Tags: grammaticality, abbreviations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When “etc.” is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)

What is the proper way to end a sentence with "etc."?  Should there be two periods or just one?

Comment: Nice question, though: the original got 14 votes.