# Do you put double dots when a contraction occurs at the end of the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When “etc.” is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)

Is it grammatically correct to use two dots at the end of the contraction 'etc' when it comes at the end of the sentence? For example,

```
All he eats is junk food: ice-cream, pizza, burger etc..
```

Or should be put just one dot there? like

```
All he eats is junk food: ice-cream, pizza, burger etc.
```

I am asking because my auto-correct is bugging me.