# If a question ends in the abbreviation of et cetera, do you still add the period before the question mark?

Tags: punctuation, periods, question-mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When “etc.” is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)

Example:

How do I pay for the bananas, oranges, etc.?

or

How do I pay for the bananas, oranges, etc?