# Period after abbreviation (Ltd)

Tags: periods

Where should periods be placed in this sentence:

> "XYX signed the contract with ABDC Ltd (ABCL)."

Should there be a period after Ltd, or is just one period after the paranthesis OK?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You're asking about how to write abbreviations - I think this would be better asked at the [English Language Learners](http://www.ell.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: maybe i was not clear ... I am not asking about abbreviations. My question is simple. I have a company name that ends with, say, Inc (period needed) or Ltd (period) - now after mentioning the company name, I am putting the acroyn of the company in paranthesis and the sentence ends immediately.... So to repeat my question --- and this is just an example -- "The California-based Berkeley Pet Society on Friday signed a contract with Texas Lovers of Pet, Inc. (TLPI). Do i use a period after Inc or after (TLPI) or after both?

Comment: Then the sentence doesn't end immediately after the abbreviation, it ends after the parenthesis. Why would't you use a period wherever it's required? (NB - possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it)).

Comment: (I apologise for editing your question title, if that wasn't your meaning. Please feel free to change it back as you please).

Comment: JHCL ...I think my question is different. In the example you connected me to ... It's about using a period inside a parenthesis and one after the parenthesis ... My problem is I have an Inc - which needs a period - and this is immediately followed by the acronym in parenthesis and because the sentence ends, I have to have a period after that - get it?.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to clarify. Perhaps include in full the options you're considering.

Comment: Somebody is closing questions left right and centre  as being suitable for ELL, including this one. Which is absolutely crazy.

Answer (score 5):

This is a matter of using a proper name with a style of punctuation.  Your first guide should be the usage preferred by the named entity itself.  Use whatever Acme Brocade, Decoration, and Costumers, Limited calls itself, whether that be

> ABDCL
>   ABDC, Ltd
>   ABDC, Ltd.

or other combination of their choosing.

Style guides differ.  [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-abbreviations) says that initialisms like ABDC and NASA don't use periods and neither do abbreviations using the the first and last letter of the word abbreviated.  That means

> Mr Dr Ltd and US

They do note some American exceptions (e.g, U.S.).  *The Chicago Manual of Style*, however, puts the period after Mr. and Dr.

*Chicago* recommends dropping an abbreviating period at the end of a sentence and dropping all punctuation except terminal (i.e., sentence ending) punctuation before a closing parenthesis.  If the company or your style guide required a period -- Ltd. -- then

> XYX signed the contract with ABDC, Ltd.
>  XYX signed the contract
>   with ABDC, Ltd. (ABCL).
>  XYX signed the contract with the company
>   (ABDC Ltd).

Answer (score 0):

Periods as abbreviation and acronym signifiers are not necessary anymore and lately. I think it's a cultural thing because we see the redundancy with N.A.S.A. and after decades we get tired of being told "this stands for something else".

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Who is this "we" you speak of?