# Where do I place the closing character when I end a sentence with parenthesis?

Tags: punctuation, writing, parentheses, periods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the period go when using parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/where-does-the-period-go-when-using-parentheses)

Which of the following should I use? Are there any exceptions to the rule?

> 1. I enjoy breakfast (sometimes).
> 2. I enjoy breakfast (sometimes.)