# Dot and parenthesis at the end of line/sentence, how to deal?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, parentheses, endings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the period go when using parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/where-does-the-period-go-when-using-parentheses)

If I had a parenthesis at the end of the sentence, do I put the dot before or after it?

For example, do I write:

> I have an example sentence (which ends with parenthesis).

or

> I have an example sentence (which ends with parenthesis.)