# How do I deal with quotation marks, parenthesis and period all at the end of a sentence?

Tags: commas, parentheses, periods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the period go when using parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/where-does-the-period-go-when-using-parentheses)

I have never seen this particular issue addressed; I looked around and couldn't see anything that **specifically** addresses this. (Is there anything?)

In a sentence in which we have this scenario: quotation marks, period and closing parenthesis, what goes where?

Any of these are possibilities:

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of **'Juno.')**
>   I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of **'Juno).'**
>   I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of **'Juno').**

I know I could use a comma instead of parentheses, but what if I wanted to use parentheses? There has to be a way to do it correctly.

Comment: I am closing this as a dupe. Even though that other question does not mention quotation marks, it does eradicate two out of your three options.

Answer (score 7):

The correct one is your third variation.

1. Parentheses belong before end-of-sentence punctuation unless the entire sentence is inside parentheses.
2. The film title *Juno* is part of the parenthetical expression, so the single-quotes around it belong inside the parentheses.

So you should have:

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of 'Juno').

Answer (score 6):

The third. The period comes at the end of the sentence and Juno requires quotation marks before ‘J’ and after ‘o’ because it’s the name of a film. An alternative is to show Juno in italics. For guidance on punctuation in general I recommend Larry Trask's ['Guide to Punctuation'](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node00.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one more combination: *I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of 'Juno'.)*

But that's not right either. Your number three is. The answer to build outwards: *Juno* is in quotation marks; then the parenthetical phrase is in brackets; then the sentence finishes with a full-stop.

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of 'Juno').

And the task is made easier if the title is written in italics, as is customary:

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of *Juno*).

Comment: I can't say I find that fourth combination remotely acceptable. As you imply, a (bracketed) parenthetical phrase could be totally deleted. Which would leave you without a period to end the sentence remaining.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not acceptable. It's just omitted from the original list of three.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I think you should make an edit and say that in your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Your third option is correct -- though I assume you wouldn't normally use the bold.

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of 'Juno').

Personally, I'd put "Juno" in italics, but that wouldn't answer your question.

> I love Diablo Cody (Oscar-winning writer of *Juno*).