# Commas inside or outside the parenthetical?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should the comma after "tacalcitol" go inside or outside the parenthesis?

"Rotate therapy with topical vitamin D analogues (calcipotriene, tacalcitol,) retinoids, anthralin, or tar preparations."

Comment: See [Where does the period go when using parentheses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/where-does-the-period-go-when-using-parentheses/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comma should be outside, as to separate "vitamin D" and "retinoids".
Hope it helps!